# Facebook app that posts to all its users in a specific time (php)

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

It's my first question on stackoverflow. I made this application and it works fine for posting a photo to a user's wall once he visit the app page, **But what I really want is to post many photos in a scheduled way (at a specific time like 12 Feb 2013 10:00 pm) to his wall and all users wall**

I made a MySQL database that contains a table for users' ID, and a table for posts' info and time.

What can I do next?

```
include ("../facebook/facebook.php") ; 

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  =>  APP_ID ,
  'secret' =>  APP_SECRET ,
  'fileUpload' => true,
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);



            $photo ="images/image1.jpg" ; 
        $message= "My message ";
            $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', array(
                                             'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                             'message' => $message,
                                             )
                                          );

  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, publish_stream, photo_upload')  
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@kareem : In simple words you can have a loop statement for the same.

```
  for($i=0;$i<$upperLimit;$i++)
 {
   $photo ="images/image".$i."jpg" ; 
    $message= "My message ";
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', array(
                                         'source' => '@' . $photo,
                                         'message' => $message,
                                         )
                                      );
  }
```

$upperLimit is the limit , till which you are planning to post the image on users wall.

Note: you can have a set of Images in a location as **image1...imagen**,so that you can loop around the images while posting on user wall

if required you can add a timer inside the for loop for some delay

Comment: I'm really sorry @Dreamweiver but I meant by scheduled posting is to post to users wall in a specific time even if his Facebook session is close !! 

Like posting to all apps users a message at 10:00 pm and 6:00 pm daily !!

Comment: well in that case @kareem, you can add a code which checks for user who is logged into FB (using his user id,as it is unique and only criteria for differentiating any user on FB) in a timely fashion like you meationed at 10pm and 6 pm daily. as far as i know all the apps works same way.

Comment: @kareem : one suggestion from my side is that you can add a FB page for your app and post on your page at specific timing. by making a user like your page, user will be able to see your app posts on his time line :)